# Why activeEvent is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

im building a calendar using react, redux, firebase and react big calendar. On the main page i have 2 calendars that are the same but connected to a different collection in firebase each one. In the redux extension it shows me the activeEvent (the info of the event, when its clicked) but when i do a `console.log(activeEvent)` in the function that triggers the activeEvent i get `undefined`

[image: activeEvent]

[image: console]

the calendarSlice:

```
 name: "calendar",
  initialState: {
    events: {},
    activeEvent: null,
    isLoadingEvents: true,
  },
  reducers: {
    onSetActiveEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.activeEvent = payload;
    },
    onAddEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      if (!state.events[payload.calendarId]) {
        state.events[payload.calendarId] = [];
      }
      state.events[payload.calendarId].push(payload.event);
      state.activeEvent = null;
    },
    onUpdateEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.events[payload.calendarId] = state.events[payload.calendarId].map((event) =>
        event.id === payload.event.id ? payload.event : event
      );
    },

    onDeleteEvent: (state) => {
      if (state.activeEvent?.calendarId) {
        state.events[state.activeEvent.calendarId] = state.events[state.activeEvent.calendarId]
          .filter((event) => event._id !== state.activeEvent._id);
        state.activeEvent = null;
      }
    },
    setEvent: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.events[payload.calendarId] = payload.events;
    },
```

useCalendarStore:

```
const useCalendarStore = (nombre) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { events, activeEvent } = useSelector((state) => state.calendar.events);
  const calendars = useSelector(state => state.calendar.events[`${nombre}`]);


  const setActiveEvent = (activeEvent) => {
    dispatch(onSetActiveEvent(activeEvent));
  };

  const startLoadingEvents = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, `${nombre}`));
    const events = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      events.push({
        id: doc.id,
        start: doc.data().start.toDate(),
        end: doc.data().end.toDate(),
        title: doc.data().title,
        notes: doc.data().notes,
      });
    });
    dispatch(setEvent({ calendarId: nombre, events }));
  };

  const startSavingEvent = async (calendarEvent) => {
    if (calendarEvent.id) {
      dispatch(onUpdateEvent({ ...calendarEvent }));
      const docRef = doc(db, `/${nombre}/${calendarEvent.id}`)
      await (setDoc(docRef, calendarEvent, {merge:true}))
    } else {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, `${nombre}`), {
        ...calendarEvent,
        _id: new Date().getTime(),
      });
      dispatch(onAddEvent({ calendarId: nombre, events }));
    }
  };


  const deleteEvent = async () => {
    deleteDoc(doc(db, `/${nombre}/${activeEvent.id}`));
    dispatch(onDeleteEvent());
  };
```

github: https://github.com/guidomora/peluqueria-new-calendar.git

deploy: https://peluqueria-new-calendar.vercel.app/

Comment: if(data === undefined) return;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggested changes to the `calendarSlice` code to handle storing multiple calendars, you'll need to also pass that `calendarId` in the dispatched actions.

The stored `state.calendar.activeEvent` should have the following type:

```js
{ calendar: string; event: Event; } | null
```

where `Event` is:

```js
{
  id: string;
  start: string;
  end: string;
  title: string;
  notes: string;
}
```

Pass the `nombre` as the `calendarId` and `activeEvent` as the `event` you want to set as the active event in state.

```js
const setActiveEvent = (activeEvent) => {
  dispatch(onSetActiveEvent({
    calendarId: nombre,
    event: activeEvent,
  }));
};
```

The delete action should reference the `calendarId` and `event` properties of the `state.activeEvent` to reference the correct events calendar and event array element to remove.

```js
const deleteEvent = async () => {
  // activeEvent is potentially null, so guard null accesses
  if (activeEvent?.event.id) {
    deleteDoc(doc(db, `/${nombre}/${activeEvent.event.id}`));
    dispatch(onDeleteEvent());
  }
};
```

```js
onDeleteEvent: (state) => {
  if (state.activeEvent?.calendarId) {
    state.events[state.activeEvent.calendarId] = state.events[state.activeEvent.calendarId]
      .filter((event) => event.id !== state.activeEvent.event.id);
    state.activeEvent = null;
  }
},
```

Comment: i couldnt understand the first 2 parts `{ calendar: string; event: Event; } | null` and `{
  id: string;
  start: string;
  end: string;
  title: string;
  notes: string;
}`  where should is use them? thanks a lot for the help i really appreciate it!

Comment: the problem that im having is that, when i add a new event from tobias calendar it saves it on the karina's calendar. It seems that the calendarID is set to "karina" but in the redux extension in the active event when i click in the button to add an event it says "tobias"

Comment: @guido Those snippets where me just trying to explain the types of values that are stored/referenced, nothing you'd use in Javascript code. If it's not too much trouble do you think you could stand up a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we could inspect live?

Comment: i could solve it! thanks a lot. Everything is working now!!